# MySql making two new fields by pulling text from an existing field

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a very large database and need to separate out the `name` field into first and last names. I was able to get the last names into a new field using

```
set lastname = trim(left(name, instr(name, ',' )))
```

(then I removed the trailing comma)

But I am having trouble getting the first names to pull correctly. The names are in the following format: `BRETE,BARBARA M`

I am fine with the initials being included. It doesn't have to be pretty, it just needs to display everything except the last name. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SUBSTRING` from one position after the comma should work.  Try:

```
set firstname = trim(substring(name, instr(name, ',' ) + 1))
```

You could also get the last name without the trailing comma using this:

```
set lastname = trim(left(name, instr(name, ',' ) - 1))
```